# how to generate code in second UImap from existing recording

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new to codedUI and for a start I am reading a lot about what should be a best practice.
I have read that if you are using complex application that is advisable to use multiple UImaps. Although I can not see a benefit at the moment I have created small project with two UImaps.

In the first initial setup (with initial UImap and CodedUITest1) I can choose whether to use Test builder or existing action recording for generating code. What ever I do it 'goes' to initial UImap. When I create new UI, test builder is started and I can record some actions and when I save it, it is added to newly created UImap in my case called AdvanceSettings. But I can not generate code from existing recording. Why is that? I would like to create automated test cases based on manual test cases with recordings.

Below is my code. I am using CodedUITest1 class for both UImaps. Should I use new class for
every UImap?

If you have some comments on code please do write some.

As I see it. Multiple UImaps are used if you have complex application so you can more easily change something. every GUI element has one UImap so if something changes on that GUI you only edit that UImap. But if you have one UImap and you use proper naming you can also easily replace or re-record certain method. So I am missing big picture with multiple UImaps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;
using EAEP.AdvanceSettingsClasses;

namespace EAEP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CodedUITest1
    /// </summary>
    [CodedUITest]
    public class CodedUITest1
    {
        public CodedUITest1()
        {
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitializationForTest()
        {

            this.UIMap.AppLaunch();

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void MainGUIMethod()
        {
            // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
            // For more information on generated code, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179463

            this.UIMap.AssertMethod1();
            this.UIMap.RestoreDefaults();
            this.UIMap.AssertMethod1();

            }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AdvanceSettignsWindowMethod()
        {

            AdvanceSettings advanceSettings = new AdvanceSettings();

            advanceSettings.MoreSettingsReopenedAfterCancel();
            this.UIMap.AssertVerificationAfterCancel();
            advanceSettings.MoreSettingsReopenedAfterOK();
            this.UIMap.AssertVerificationAfterOK();

        }

        #region Additional test attributes

        // You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:

        ////Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
        //[TestInitialize()]
        //public void MyTestInitialize()
        //{        
        //    // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        //    // For more information on generated code, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179463
        //}

        ////Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
        //[TestCleanup()]
        //public void MyTestCleanup()
        //{        
        //    // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        //    // For more information on generated code, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179463
        //}

        #endregion


        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }
        private TestContext testContextInstance;

        public UIMap UIMap
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.map == null))
                {
                    this.map = new UIMap();
                }

                return this.map;
            }
        }

        private UIMap map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cann't use multiple UI Maps with the from existing recording feature. this feature always generates code in a map called UIMap. I've explained a bit about these limitation in a blog post i did about integrating specflow with Coded Ui tests

http://rburnham.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/record-your-coded-ui-test-methods/

If you want to use Multiple UIMaps for better maintainability you have to use this method

1. Record each action individually by right clicking the UIMap and selecting Coded UI Test Builder.
2. Manually wire up the test to the actions by creating a blank Coded UI Test, update the UIMap it references and then in the test methods call the required actions to perform the test.

Its a limitation that makes what is good about the MTM integration pointless.

Comment: I did it in that way like you described. I am suppose to build automation and my wish was to relay on manual test cases. I guess I will do it in two ways until I see which way suites best our needs. One more question. When you use multiple UImaps you are using only one CodedUITest class or? I have also problem getting the big picture how to build automation structure. Should one CodedUITest class represent like Test Suite where TestMethod represent TestCase? txn for the answer it very helpful.

Comment: No you can have multiple Coded UI Test Classes per UIMap and vice versa. A Coded UI Test Class would normally represent a feature that you are testing. Like the Checkout feature of a Shopping Cart. The class can have many Test Methods which normally represent the scenario your testing, Like CheckupAnPayByCash. The recordings in the UIMap are best to be small and reusable. Like the action involved in getting to the Checkout Screen would be one recording called Checkout. I would have a UIMap called ShoppingCart so in many test cases you can just call ShoppingCart.Checkout()

Comment: I Agree that it would have been good to rely on Manual Tests as a starting point but they still haven't fixed this area. It was the main thing that drove us to using MTM. When i checked in the VS2012 preview they still hadn't fixed this. I guess the work on their ALM feature was a higher priority. Hopefully they release a patch soon.

Comment: Txn for the info. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Having multiple UIMaps speeds the test execution. Additionally this makes editions, assertions, properties and settings a lot easier.
2. To create tests for the second UIMap you just right click on it and press "Edit With Coded UI Test Builder"

Regarding the `But I can not generate code from existing recording. Why is that?` I have no clue - what do you mean by `can not`?

Comment: I am working only with one CodedUITest1 class. When you go to TEST->Generate code for coded UI test -> then you have possibility to choose between 'test builder' or 'existing recording' Which ever option I choose created methods are bind to first(initial) UIMap. I did way you desribed and this is OK but only if I do not want to use existing recording from some manual test case from test manager.